# Safe silver electroplating solutions

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, silver

Are there any practical, sane and safe solutions that can be used for silver elctroplating/electrolysis that are purchasable?

Objective is to create silver crystals, but without having evil cyanide floating around the house... copper I can handle with copper sulphate.  Silver has me stuck...

Any ideas?

Comment: Silver nitrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried to grow big crystals or anything, but we commonly use 30 mM silver nitrate in 1 M $\ce{NH4OH}$ for electrodepositing silver onto metal (usually gold) electrodes.
If you don't care what kind of surface finish you end up with, it will work, but it makes a fairly rough film that can be somewhat easily removed with abrasion.
The tricky part is trying to get very smooth and adherent films.
It [seems](http://www2.bren.ucsb.edu/~dturney/port/papers/Modern%20Electroplating/05.pdf) that there are still not any good replacements for electroplating from cyanide-containing solutions, for decorative or engineering purposes where the deposit will be subject to wear or has to look nice.

Comment: As both responders above mention, silver nitrate should work well, especially fo small crystals. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnyBldC4Ra4

Comment: There isn't a safe option is what I was afraid of... but I wasn't enough of a chemist to be sure :(