# Gold Chloride as electroplating solution?

Tags: electrochemistry, electroplating

In some (maybe questionable) pedagogical texts at least, gold chloride solution is presented as an electrolyte in the electro deposition of gold.

In practice however, it seems that cyanide based solutions are used instead. Please excuse my ignorance, this is not my field of study, but could gold chloride be actually used in practice as an electrolyte?

The application is electroplating 304, 316 stainless steel and cast iron ornaments.

Comment: It would be rather H[AuCl4]. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroauric_acid

Comment: Note that generally, electroplating is easy. Quality electroplating (durability, shine) is difficult. It took a lot of experimenting to determine the right metal compound, auxiliary components and current density to achieve desired results. Many solutions for electroplating were initially kept as trade secrets.

Comment: Electrolysis of gold chloride solutions (or $\ce{HAuCl4^-}$)  produces a rough, dusty and pulverulent gold deposit, which is not really adherent. To get a bright and continuous gold deposit, electrolysis must be carried out with gold cyanide, because in gold cyanide solutions, the concentration of $\ce{Au^{3+}}$ ions is extremely low. And this rather low concentration is necessary to get a nice bright, shiny and continuous gold plating.

Comment: The necessity of keeping the ionic concentration as low as possible is well explained in the document published on December 23, about silver plating.

Comment: This one:  [why-is-silver-cyanide-used-for-electroplating](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/170118/why-is-silver-cyanide-used-for-electroplating)

Comment: Electroplating is one of the true black arts of chemistry…